# Azure table storage service context continues to throw up the same error if it encounters one error

Tags: c#, iis, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

When i try to update or create an entity on azure table storage, it sometimes throws up an error like "Entity already exists" or "One of the request inputs is out of range", and after that if i try to create or update some other entity on that table also ,it continues to throw up the same error. There is no problem with the input as if I restart the iis server, it starts working again. I have no clue why thats happening.

I tried different SaveChangesOptions including "ContinueOnError" but the table service context continues to throw up error on all further updates/creates after it encounters one error.

Below is my code on how am creating the table storage service context.

Please let me know what the issue could be, this has been a huge blocker for me as major functionalities in my app stop working if the table service context encounters just one error.

```
public class AudioRecordRepository : Repository<PersistedAudioRecord>, IAudioRecordRepository
{
    private TableStorageServiceContext<PersistedAudioRecord> audioRecordServiceContext;
    private CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount;

    public AudioRecordRepository(IServiceContext<PersistedAudioRecord> serviceContext)
        : base(serviceContext)
    {
        if (RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable)
            cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("StorageConnectionString"));
        else
            cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageConnectionString"]);

        audioRecordServiceContext = new TableStorageServiceContext<PersistedAudioRecord>(TableNames.AudioRecord, cloudStorageAccount.TableEndpoint.ToString(), cloudStorageAccount.Credentials) { IgnoreResourceNotFoundException = true };

    }

    public bool CreateRecord(PersistedAudioRecord record)
    {
        this.audioRecordServiceContext.Create(record);
        this.audioRecordServiceContext.SaveChangesWithRetries(SaveChangesOptions.ContinueOnError);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you consider migrating to new version of Azure SDK for .Net. Its newer way of accessing services is simple and intuitive. Here is the link in case you want to migrate http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=254364&clcid=0x409

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the context that contains your entities (audioRecordServiceContext) is declared at the class level and it is not clear if/when it is cleared out.

Table Storage Contexts follow a "Unit of Work" design pattern.  They are designed to track entities.  If you've added a "bad" entity to your context and tried to persist, you'd obviously get an error.  However, what you need to be aware of, is that your context did not throw away the bad entity.  It is still tracking it and it still thinks you want to save it.  So, next call to SaveChanges will attempt to save it again.

Suggestion: put a "using" statement around your context and declare it inside a function only when you need to save entities - do not let it sit on a class level - unless you have a specific use case that requires it.  But if you do, then make sure to yank the failing entity out of the context object (you can do so manually by examining Entities collection of the context object)

HTH

Comment: I have edited my code. I am declaring the service context in the constructor of the class. And am accessing the service context in the methods of that class. So i guess the service context doesn't get cleared when i call the methods from my controller. One way is to detach the entity if any error is thrown? that would work? Is there any other way?

Comment: I am saving entities in multiple methods in the class, so i would prefer not to create a separate service context in each of these methods

Comment: There is really no performance impact on creating a context object.  It is not like a SQL connection where resources are used up.  Table Context is just an object that has a URL and tracks entities.  You need to make a choice, if you need to share the entities inside the context between function calls - you should take ownership and clean up the bad ones.  Otherwise, instantiate new context every time and entity tracking will be function-specific

Answer (score 0):

You can recreate the TableServiceContext object for the given table.

```
TableServiceContext tableServiceContext = tableClient.GetDataServiceContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to Storage Library 2.0, it's much better, supports far more in terms of querying, and is quite a bit faster to boot.